# Why does the alias I have created not execute in the path I am expecting?

Tags: unix, path, zsh, alias, pwd

I have created an alias that is intended to copy to my clipboard whichever path I am in, in the terminal.

The alias is in my `.zshrc` file.

The alias looks as follows:

```
alias cpath="echo -n `pwd`|pbcopy"
```

When I execute the following command in my terminal it always works:

```
echo -n `pwd`|pbcopy
```

However, when I use the alias `cpath`, it copies whichever path was the path when I first opened a particular terminal. For example, if I open a terminal in the `/Users/tommyrharper` directory, then I run `cpath`, it will copy the following path to my clipboard: `/Users/tommyrharper`.

If I then `cd` into my `Documents` folder, then run `cpath`, then it will still just add `/Users/tommyrharper` to my clipboard.

However If I then directly run `` echo -n `pwd`|pbcopy `` it will add `/Users/tommyrharper/Documents` to my clipboard.

If I initially opened a terminal in `/Users/tommyrharper/Documents` and then I run `cpath`, then it will add `/Users/tommyrharper/Documents` to my clipboard.

But then again if I `cd` into my `Notes` directory, then I run `cpath`, it will still just add `/Users/tommyrharper/Documents` to my clipboard.

Why is my alias not behaving in the same way as when I directly enter the command in the terminal?

And is there a way to get my alias to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the backtick command substitution in your alias (`` `pwd` ``) gets run when zsh sources `.zshrc` when it starts up. This is because you have used doubles quotes, which evaluate substitutions.

You can confirm this by running `alias cpath`, which will display the definition of the alias, which should now include a path instead of a literal `` `pwd` ``.

If you instead define your alias like this with single quotes (which do not evaluate substitutions):

```
alias cpath='echo -n `pwd`|pbcopy'
```

it will work as expected.

More details on the different quoting styles and substitutions can be found here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Not only do I have the solution now but I understand why it previously was not working, and why your solution works. Thanks for the great response :)